# play sound clips in iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm new to iphone development. i want to write an app that has 3 buttons. touching each will trigger a sound.

> - 1.wav
> - 2.wav
> - 3.wav

Can someone give me some hints and guide me to the right path?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to write actions in a controller that trigger the sounds and hook the buttons up to those actions.

Comment: do you know where can i find some samples?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to play .wav files on button click event:

```
-(void) playWavFile{
       SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;
       CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL (CFBundleGetMainBundle (),CFSTR ("1"),CFSTR ("wav"),NULL );
       AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef,&soundFileObject );
       AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
}

-(IBAction) button1Pressed:(id)sender
{
       [self playWavFile];
}
```

Thanks,

 Jim.